# Нужно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли тире в поговорке "Сила есть (—) ума не надо"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно. нужно. Бессоюзное сложное предложение, в первой части содержится условие того. о чем говорится во второй. Если сила есть, то ума не надо.